# JJWT parse JWS token using RSA public key bytes

Tags: java, rsa, jjwt

**Context:**

My service validates JWS coming from multiple sources; each source shares a base64 key that must be used to validate their JWS. I don't have any restrictions on the algorithm they want to use to sign their JWS.

I use [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) to parse/verify the JWS, and I noticed that the `byte[] signingKey` is supported only for HMAC signatures, while it fails for RSA/EC signatures:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes can only be specified for HMAC signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
        at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:35)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:363)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:529)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:589)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173)
```

I found out ([issue-86](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/86#:%7E:text=(so%20for%20that%2C%20the%20key%20resolver%20concept%20fits%2C%20so%20let%27s%20implement%20that%20in%20this%20vaporware)%3A)) that you can implement a `io.jsonwebtoken.SigningKeyResolverAdapter` to provide a `java.security.Key` after parsing the headers; doing this allows you to also know the type of algorithm, provide a `Key` accordingly, and to correctly verify the token signature.

Here is the code I used to retrieve an RSA public key from bytes:

```java
final String publicKeyBase64 = "...";
final byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyBase64);
final KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
final X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpec)
```

**Questions:**

Since this approach is not the default on the JJWT library, are there any drawbacks / problems?

Why are `byte[]` keys only handled for HMAC algorithms?

---

```java
package com.stackoverflow.jjwt;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwsHeader;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SigningKeyResolverAdapter;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final KeyPair pair = Keys.keyPairFor(SignatureAlgorithm.RS512);
        final PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
        final PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();

        // this is the public key in base64 that a source may share with me
        final String publicKeyBase64 = Base64.getEncoder()
                .encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());

        // this is the token that my service need to verify
        final String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject("Hurray!")
                .signWith(privateKey)
                .compact();

        decode(token, publicKeyBase64);
        // ↳ Exception: Key bytes can only be specified for HMAC signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.

        decodeWithCustomResolver(token, publicKeyBase64);
        // ↳ Subject: Hurray!
    }

    public static void decode(final String token, final String publicKeyBase64) {
        try {
            final byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder()
                    .decode(publicKeyBase64);
            final String subject = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(publicKeyBytes)
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes can only be specified for HMAC signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
            //     at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:35)
            //     at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:363)
            //     at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:529)
            //     at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:589)
            //     at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173)
            //     at com.stackoverflow.jjwt.Test.decode(Test.java:52)
            //     at com.stackoverflow.jjwt.Test.main(Test.java:38)
        }
    }

    public static void decodeWithCustomResolver(final String token, final String publicKeyBase64) {
        final SigningKeyResolverAdapter resolver = new SigningKeyResolverAdapter() {
            @Override
            public Key resolveSigningKey(final JwsHeader header, final Claims claims) {
                final SignatureAlgorithm alg = SignatureAlgorithm.forName(header.getAlgorithm());
                if (alg.isHmac()) {
                    // cannot be used for asymmetric key algorithms (RSA, Elliptic Curve)
                    final byte[] keyBytes = this.resolveSigningKeyBytes(header, claims);
                    return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, alg.getJcaName());
                } else if (alg.isRsa()) {
                    try {
                        final byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder()
                                .decode(publicKeyBase64);
                        final KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                        final X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
                        return (PublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpec);
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("RSA found, but with invalid key", e);
                    }
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Elliptic Curve not supported yet"); // etc.
            }
        };
        try {
            final String subject = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKeyResolver(resolver)
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
            // ↳ Subject: Hurray!
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally, it is known which algorithm was used to sign a token, so that the key type for verification is determined. If, as in your case, it is not known which algorithm was used to sign the token, so that the key type for verification is undetermined, you only have the option of retrieving this information from the header in order to select the appropriate key.

Comment: @Topaco the question is why did they decide to parse the key from a byte array only for HMAC? Is it only because RSA/EC has two branches (public/private) and they didn't want to assume that it was a public key? As far as I know my decode method should work fine, but I can't figure out if I am missing something.

Comment: Keys for different algorithms generally have completely different formats, which is why there is no *simple* way of determining which key in which format for which algorithm is involved using only the `byte[]`. However, this information is required for the key import. To eliminate this ambiguity, the library apparently restricts `setSigningKey(byte[])` to HMACs (BTW, deprecated since  0.12.0).

Comment: In contrast, if the key is available as an object that implements the `Key` interface (`SecretKey`, `PrivateKey`, `PublicKey` etc.), the required information on the key is available so that `signWith(Key)`/`verifyWith(SecretKey/PublicKey))` can be used to specify *any* key (HMAC keys, RSA keys etc.).

Comment: If the key information is not contained in the key itself or more precisely cannot be easily determined (as in the case of `byte[]`), it can alternatively be determined from the header before the key import. This is what the resolver approach does. It uses the information from the header to generate keys from a `byte[]` array that implement the `Key` interface.